# Clustering points to reach global minimum

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, partition

For a number of points, for example, 100 points, each two has a 'connection' (a number), the goal of the algorithm is to split those points into a given number of clusters (like 5 clusters), minimized the total connections insides clusters.

---

input: 
A matrix with shape n * n, the matrix[i][j] describe the connection between point i and j (the matrix should be symmetry matrix). The cluster number m.

output:
m clusters for n points. And the total connections inside clusters are minimized.

T= ∑(C⊆m)∑(i,j⊆C)M_ij

(Goal is to minimize T above)

```
For example: 5 points with the matrix
    1   2   3   4  5 
1  0.1 0.1 0.3 0.5 0.7
2  0.1 0.1 0.7 0.9 1.1
3  0.3 0.7 0.5 0.1 0.2
4  0.5 0.9 0.1 0.3 0.5
5  0.7 1.1 0.2 0.5 0.1
To split into 2 clusters, the splitting
Cluster 1: {1,2}
Cluster 2: {3,4,5}
has the total internal connection of T = C1 + C2 = M12 + M34 + M35 + M45 = 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.2 + 0.5 = 0.9

The splitting
Cluster 1: {1,3,4}
Cluster 2: {2,5}
Has the total internal connection  T = C1 + C2 = M13 + M14 + M34 + M25 =  0.3 + 0.5 + 0.1 + 1.1 = 2.0
```

The goal is to find the lowest internal connection

This is easy when n and m is small, just loop all possible case to find the global minimum. but when n and m become bigger, iteration is not possible.

---

I have tried Kernighan–Lin algorithm to solve this problem. Initialize with random splitting, then defined two behavior, inserting the point into another cluster, and swap two points in two clusters, each time to find the behavior that can lower the total connections insides clusters mostly. Applied this behavior, then re-calculate again, until no more insertion/swapping can lower the total connections. (Greedy algorithm Strategy).

However it can only reach local minimum, with different initialization, the results also are different. Is there a standard way to solve this problem to reach the global minimum?

Comment: Without knowing how connection is defined, there is probably not much to exploit.

Comment: The connection is just a random number, like the edge in the graph.

Comment: So there is no mathematical-structure to exploit like for metrics (triangle ineq and co.)? Well.. not much you can do besides brute-force. And *The connection is just a random number, like the edge in the graph.* is pretty informal.

Comment: Sorry for the informal description. I have updated the question now, does it make more sense to you? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is supposedly NP hard, so either you use a local optimum,or you have to try all O(k^n) possibilities.

You can use a local optimum to bound your search, but there is no guarantee that this helps much.